# SSRS Indicator Not Displaying

Tags: reporting-services, indicator

I have a report written out of Report Builder 3.0. The Value is the following expression:

```
=iif(Avg(Fields!Length.Value) > Avg(Fields!Duration.Value),1,0)
```

I have the Measurement Unit set to: Numeric.

The indicator icons are as follows:

[image]

This displays perfectly on my report, but *only* if I am on Print Layout view.

[image]

Otherwise it's blank:

[image]

I have encountered this with charts before and typically ignore it (once I export everything is fine). The problem is, if I try to export it to a pdf, even a tiff it is *not* displaying the indicator. Neither will excel, or any other format I've tried.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the "Indicator Properties" menu "Value and States" tab make sure that "States Measurement Unit" is "Numeric".
This helped me in similar case.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue.  Reports run against our SSRS server failed to display indicators, except in Print Layout.

We were able to resolve it by upgrading our SSRS server to SQL 2014 SP1.